# Why is this condition true when the player is walking?

Tags: unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

[My Blueprint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1yJd.png)

I have the following blueprint: when I press a button, a boolean is set to true. Later, after running through a loop with a delay, it should be reset. However, during the running process, the branch is often false. Any idea why?

Created a blueprint for a grid player system